# Cast to ObjectId failed for value on findById

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get a single item from Mongodb, Mongoose with the code below. In Postman make a get request with an Id to
 http://localhost:5000/api/report/l5c959036c3dfe2338412be8e  and the error returned is

> "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value
>   \"l5c959036c3dfe2338412be8e\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Report\

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost:27017/reports",
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
);
mongoose.connection.on(
  "error",
  console.error.bind(console, "connection error:")
);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.get("/api/report/:id", (req, res) => {
  Report.findById(req.params.id, (err, report) => {
    if (err) return res.status(404).send({ message: err.message });
    return res.send({ report });
  });
});
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: `l5c959036c3dfe2338412be8e` is not a valid objectId. Remove the  `l` from the begning of the id.

Comment: Means what it says. `l5c959036c3dfe2338412be8e` is not valid for an `ObjectId` value. `5c959036c3dfe2338412be8e` **without the "l" on the beginning** is however valid. I suggest a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the "I" from the objectId you pass as the param, as suggested in the comments.